# Reference an arrays key in its value

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I know this seems like something that should be averted by design, but let's just say it is bitterly needed:
Is it possible to reference the key belonging to a value while it is being initialized?

Here is what I imagine it to be (not exactly the case in which I need it, but the key is primitive as well):

```
$array = array(25 => "My key is " . $this->key);
```

I need this because the array key is used in each value. Actually the value is another array which has a value in which the first array key is used. Like I said in the comments, I want to keep it DRY. Doing it is no problem, but I want to do it good ;)

Comment: What would the output look like ?

Comment: Is this an associative array or a regular array (aka with keys from 0..n)?

Comment: why not just do it like this `array(25,...)`?

Comment: It is an associative array.
Bad design in a program that was developed before my time and now I have to fix it.

Comment: I think what you are asking here is a way to implement your solution, not your actual question. There is a reason why you think you need this, if you could add that (instead of "bad design"), we could help you find an actual solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to reference the key when defining the value. Except maybe writing a preprocessor that embeds it in the string. But that would only work for primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an array yourself you can just put key value to array value like:

```
$array = array(25 => "My key is 25");
```

If you are have an array already you can use a `foreach` and add all keys to it's values:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = sprintf('%s %s', $value, $key);
}
```

Or if you just want to have an array of keys of existing array you can use either [array_flip](http://php.net/array_flip) if you want to maintain key=>value, but have keys and values flipped. Or you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) if you want just an array of keys.

To make what you want: initialize an array somewhere and do not add any keys to it's value you can implement [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/ArrayAccess), [Countable](http://php.net/Countable) and have:

```
public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset($this->container[$offset]) 
                ? $this->container[$offset] . ' ' . $offset 
                : null;
}
```

or something like this. But in this case you need to have a variable that contains this array to be an instance of your `ArrayAccess` implementation. And depending of usage of this class you probably will need to implement more interfaces.

Comment: I want to keep it try, that's why 1 is not prefered (any why am I asking the question).
2 is not an option because I want to do this while the array is being initialized.

Comment: Then just add a key value where array is being initialized.

Comment: Oops, I wanted to write "DRY" instead of try. I don't want to have redundancies.